# Bulk create Apple in-app purchase consumables

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I´m creating a sequel of a game. All the consumable products will be the same at both games.
I have a list of almost 200 consumable products that I have to create at apple store connect, in this new app.
At Google Play I was able to bulk create all this at once but I can´t find anyting about it when it comes to apple store.
Any ideas if there is a solution?
thanks : )

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763147/1128713

Comment: That´s exactly what I needed. Thanks!